# Calling a function inside enum's function in the same class

Tags: ios, swift

I came across a scenario where i had to call a function inside enum's function in swift 3.
The scenario is as follows:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

enum Address {
    case primary
    case secondary

    func getAddress() {

       let closure = { (text: String) in
            showAlert(for: "")
        }
    }
}

func showAlert(for text: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: text, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:NSLocalizedString("OK", comment:"OK button title"), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

As you can see from the above code I get an error on line 10 `(showAlert(for: ""))`

The error is:

> instance member showAlert cannot be used on type SomeViewController; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

How can I call a function from enum's function then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alternative approach:**

You can use a `static method` of `SomeViewController` to present the `alert`.

***Example:***

```
static func showAlert(for text: String)
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: text, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:NSLocalizedString("OK", comment:"OK button title"), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

*Using it:*

```
enum Address
{
    case primary
    case secondary

    func getAddress()
    {
        let closure = { (text: String) in
            SomeViewController.showAlert(for: "")
        }
        closure("hello")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let addr = Address.primary
    addr.getAddress()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `enum` does not know the instance and thus can not access its members. One approach to deal with this situation would be to inform the client of the `enum` that something went wrong.

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    enum Address {
        case primary
        case secondary

        func getAddress() -> String? {
            //allGood == whatever your logic is to consider a valid address
            if allGood {
                return "theAddress"
            } else {
                return nil;
            }
        }
    }

    func funcThatUsesAddress() {
        let address = Address.primary
        guard let addressString = address.getAddress() else {
            showAlert(for: "")
            return
        }
        // use your valid addressString here
        print(addressString)

    }

    func showAlert(for text: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: text, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:NSLocalizedString("OK", comment:"OK button title"), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This might solve my case, but what if the function is void or you need to call this enum's function from various places?